# Denodo / SQL - Multiple conditions for AND and OR in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql-server, denodo

I'm filtering tickets on 2 tables in Denodo that record the history of all action what have been done on the tickets. What I want is to see column Keywords is Null and column templates NOT 'temp~'. I am able to achieve the first condition perfectly but 2nd one not. Well no row from that column return 'temp~' anymore but since it's historical table, it does return other actions that has been done on the ticket for eg. save, done, complete so it does still return ticket number that I am trying to filter which I don't want.

```
SELECT  A.ticket_number, A.created_on, A.keywords, B.Action
FROM table1 AS A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MAX(action) as Action, ticket_number
FROM table2 GROUP BY ticket_number) AS B on A.ticket_number= B.ticket_number 
WHERE created_on>= '2019-04-15' AND(NOT B.Action= 'Templates~' AND A.keywords IS NULL)
```

```
Actual table:
ticket_number | created_on | keywords | Action
ticket1       | 2019-04-15 | dog      | Template1
ticket1       | 2019-04-15 | dog      | Save
ticket2       | 2019-04-17 | NULL     | no_temp
ticket3       | 2019-04-20 | NULL     | no_temp
ticket2       | 2019-04-17 | NULL     | no_temp

Current results:
ticket_number | created_on | keywords | Action
ticket1       | 2019-04-15 | NULL     | Save
ticket2       | 2019-04-17 | NULL     | working
ticket3       | 2019-04-20 | NULL     | Save
ticket2       | 2019-04-17 | NULL     | complete


Expected results:
ticket_number | created_on | keywords | Action
ticket2       | 2019-04-17 | NULL     | no_temp
ticket3       | 2019-04-20 | NULL     | no_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the information provided, it seems that the result is correct.

The WHERE condition of the query is:

`WHERE created_on>= '2019-04-15' AND(NOT B.templates = 'Templates~' AND A.keywords IS NULL)`

All the rows of *Current results* meet this condition. That is

- `created_on` is equal or greater than `2019-04-15`
- The value of `templates` of the subquery `B` is **not** `null`.
- The value of `keywords` is `null`.

Comment: you are correct, but what I need is to filter the tickets that has not been flagged as "template" under the Action column. This table I'm working on saves the history of all the actions under "Actions column" that has been done on a ticket such "save, in progess, template". So I did `WHERE NOT B.Action = 'Templates~'` yes it will remove the ticket that was labelled Templates under action but the same ticket that has "save" and "in progress" under Action column will still show up.

Comment: @Jonathan, I guess you have to use a subquery for that. I guess something like 

```WHERE created_on>= '2019-04-15' 
AND A.keywords IS NULL
AND ticket_number NOT IN (SELECT ticket_number WHERE Action = 'Templates~') ```